# excel (or OR) formula to delete rows that fulfil some criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
id | Title | number of occurrences
1  | one   | 2
1  | one   | 2
16  | text   | 4
19  | more   | 7 
.....
187  | title1   | 3
187  | title2   | 3
187  | title3   | 3
```

Given the above excel columns, I cannot find a way to delete all rows that match the following criteria:

if number of occurrences == count of id number, then these row must be filtered (for deletion). Which formula should I use?

Desired output after deletion of lines:

```
16  | text   | 4
19  | more   | 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a simple helper column:

[image]

All I used was: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1)`

After drag down I just ordered on three levels:

- Column D small to large
- Column A small to large

Obviously delete all rows after D changed to 2 after this sorting.